# How to parse webpage response in android?

Tags: javascript, java, android

How do you make it so that if a website has a form let's say, and I want to pass a string into the input tag , press a button, and get the link that's generated in the other page? All of that meaning it should be done in the background, with javascript or somehow. The website in particular is http://www.listentoyoutube.com/ , I want to get the generated audio file link.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, you should look for another site that supports APIs to do such requests.